# GDB: how to see what memory addresses are accessible?

Tags: debugging, memory, assembly, gdb, postmortem-debugging

Suppose, in a debugging session I have an address which unfortunately points to some rubbish. And I want to examine memory around it to see what's located near. As expected, the following error occurs:

```
(gdb) x/64 $t5
0x842da7ac:     Cannot access memory at address 0x842da7ac
```

So, the question is: is there any way to read a range of addresses, some of which are not valid?

(More precise, how can I know that in the example above `$t5+n` is a valid address for some `0 < n <= 64`?)

Answer (score 7):

You can't read invalid addresses (obviously).

On some OSes you can can query the OS about valid addresses while the process is stopped in GDB. For example, on Linux `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` will give you info about which addresses are valid (and the access mode they are valid for). Other OSes may have similar mechanism.

Since you tagged your question `post-mortem`, you can't use above mechanism; but then you must have a `core` file. On Linux (and other `ELF` systems), `readelf -l core` will tell you which regions of memory were written into the core, which usually gives you a good idea of what memory was valid at the time of crash. However, read-only mappings are usually not written to `core`, so you may not see such mappings in `readelf` output.

All modern OSes use paging, and pages are at least `1K` (though `4K` is more common), so you can tell that the closest memory to `$t5` which could possibly be valid is `0x842da800`, and so `n >= 84` (bytes).

Finally, if you ask GDB to examine 64 words, and GDB can't examine the first one, it will stop.

However, if you are using GDB-7.x, you can ask GDB to examine one word at a time in Python, and GDB will throw Python exception if it can't examine that particular word. But since you can catch Python exceptions, it is trivial to write a script that will implement "examine next N words, ignoring any unreadable ones" in Python (which I believe answers your "how can this be done" question).

Comment: Inside gdb, you can use `maintenance info sections`, instead of `cat /proc/<pid>/maps`

Comment: No, you can't: /proc/<pid>/maps shows areas, such as sbrk and mmap, which do *not* belong to any section that GDB knows.